# Adding functionality to EF Model POCO collections for GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, design-patterns, mvvm

I’m having some difficulty working out the best way of approaching a design problem. I was hoping for some ideas / advice. It’s a WPF 4.0 desktop application.

I’m using Entity Framework (v6, model first) and it has generated `ObservableCollection`s of POCO classes for me which I’m using as the basis for my Model. I’m exposing these to my ViewModel and my intention is to expose (`ReadOnly` versions of) the collections from here to my View, but I need to add some behaviour to each object in the collection before the interface will function (this is very much “View” functionality – recording user interface state corresponding to each member of the collection, not data that should be persisted).

As I see it, I’ve got two options:

1. Add behaviour to the generated POCO classes though additional partial class definitions. This seems wrong because the POCO classes are Model classes and the functionality I need is not Model functionality.
2. Create a new class (or sub-class) for use in the ViewModel collections and synchronise the collections between the Model and the VM. The synchronisation and duplication of data seems like an ugly kludge, not to mention significant extra implementation work and runtime processing. **[EDIT: It has been suggested (not unreasonably) that this could be achieved by wrapping the original POCO objects in classes that add functionality. See below for why this is more complicated than it might first appear]**

Is there a standard way to approach this sort of problem ?

**Edit: make the problem parameters more specific**

I have a collection of `X`s, each of which holds a collection of `Y`s (because of a one -> many relationship in the DB). For Option 2 above, I would need to wrap all the `X`s and all the `Y`s. I can create a collection of `WrappedX`s relatively easily, but I can't easily go in and change each `X`'s member collection to `WrappedY`s. I'd have to clone the `Y` collections in the wrapper for X and keep all of the `Y` <> `WrappedY` collections in sync. This is the overhead that makes me uncomfortable implemnting Option 2 if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with a generic wrapper class. I use it to keep things like IsSelected out of my POCO models. Note: I do implement INotifyPropertyChanged in my POCO classes to avoid having to map all the properties to my DisplayItem but it sounds like you don't need that since yours are readonly.

```
public class DisplayItemBase<T> : ObservableObject 
{
   private T _Item;
   public T Item
   {
      get { return _Item; }
      set
      {
         if (value == _Item)
            return;

         _Item = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
      }
   }

   private bool _IsSelected;
   public bool IsSelected
   {
      get { return _Item; }
      set
      {
         if (value == _Item)
            return;

         _Item = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
      }
   }

   //More reusable properties/methods/etc
}
```

Then if I have a particular POCO entity that needs specific UI related functionality that doesn't pertain to any of my other POCO's, I create a specific class for that one that inherits from the DisplayItemBase.

```
public class MyEntityDisplayItem : DisplayItemBase<MyEntity>
{
    private DisplayItemCollectionBase<ChildEntity> _ChildEntities;
    public DisplayItemCollectionBase<ChildEntity> ChildEntities
    {
       get { return _ChildEntities; }
       set
       {
           if (value == _ChildEntities)
              return;

           _ChildEntities = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("ChildEntities");
       }
    }

    public MyEntityDisplayItem(MyEntity myEntity)
    {
        ChildEntities = new DisplayItemCollectionBase<ChildEntity>(myEntity.ChildEntities);
        Item = myEntity;
    }

    public void AddChildEntity(ChildEntity childEntity)
    {
        ChildEntities.Add(childEntity);
        Item.ChildEntities.Add(childEntity);
    }
}
```

Edit: To Answer the comment

I also create a DisplayItemCollectionBase that can take my entity, wrap it and add it to the collection like this.

```
public class DisplayItemCollectionBase<T> : ObservableCollection<DisplayItemBase<T>>
{
   public DisplayItemCollectionBase(IEnumerable<T> items)
   {
       this.AddRange(items)
   }

   public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
   {
       foreach (var item in items)
          this.Add(item);
   }

   public void Add(T item)
   {
      this.Add(new DisplayItemBase<T>(item));
   }
}
```

This might be a little off because I'm going from my head but you should get the gist.

And I use it like this (simplified) in my ViewModel:

```
public void RefreshFromDatabase()
{
    var repository = new MyEntityRepository();
    IEnumerable<MyEntity> myEntities = repository.GetAll();
    MyEntityCollection = new DisplayItemCollectionBase<MyEntity>(myEntities);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that all makes sense... but how do you keep the DisplayItems in sync with the members of the Model's collection (i.e. when new members are added, you need a new DisplayItem, etc.)? That's my real problem! (NB the collection can change, just not by direct manipulation by the GUI binding.)

Comment: Thanks. So, when it's had the sync code added to make sure `ViewModel.DisplayItemCollectionBase<>` has members corresponding to `Model.ObservableCollection<>`, this is essentially my Option 2, no? I guess I was looking for a consensus on the way forward, so I'll take this as a vote in that direction. Perhaps I overplayed the overhead (there's not really much in the way of duplication).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by keeping them in sync. I don't have a collection of my models and a collection of the DisplayItems. I only have the collection of DisplayItems because they hold my models which I can access and use when needed. I added one more method that shows how I use the models returned from the database in my viewmodel.

Comment: Perhaps we're looking at things a little differently. EF always generates a set of collections which mirror the DB content - it's how it exposes the tables and relationships. This set of collections (plus DB access code) is what I'm referring to as the Model. You seem to be referring to each of your POCO objects as a separate Model... if you look at it like that, where would business logic reside?

Comment: Yes, but you still only have one instance of your model in existence. The wrapper class is just holding a reference to an individual instance of a model, it doesn't create a clone.

Comment: This isn't really my problem. I've edited the question to explain why a wrapper is a more complicated solution for my particular problem (although any one -> many relationship could cause the same issue - my situation is not that specialised)

Comment: @BobSammers I added more detail in MyEntityDisplayItem showing how I handle that.